# Code forces runtime error (Exit code is -1073741819)

Tags: c, runtime-error

I am getting this "Exit code is -1073741819" error again and again when I'm submitting the code can anyone help me to figure it out. I was solving [this problem](https://codeforces.com/contest/1481/problem/A).

This is the code I've written. I was using GNU GCC 11 5.1.0 compiler

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

struct node
{
    long int x;
    long int y;
}space[1001];



int main()
{
    int t,tm;
    long i, j;
    long r, u, l, d;
    char* route[1000];

    scanf("%d", &t);
    tm = t;
    for(i = 0;i < t;i++)
    {
        scanf("%ld", &space[i].x);
        scanf("%ld", &space[i].y);
        route[i] = (char *)malloc(20000*sizeof(char));
        scanf("%s", route[i]);

    }

    for(i = 0;i < t;i++)
    {
        //initializing the left-right-up-down counters
        l = r = u = d = 0;

        for(j = 0;j < strlen(route[i]);j++)
        {
            if(route[i][j] == 'L')
                l--;
            else if(route[i][j] == 'R')
                r++;
            else if(route[i][j] == 'U')
                u++;
            else if(route[i][j] == 'D')
                d--;
        }

        //right-up
        if(space[i].x >= 0 && space[i].y >= 0)
        {

            if(space[i].x <= r && space[i].y <= u)
                printf("YES\n");

            else
                printf("NO\n");
        }
        //right-down
        else if(space[i].x >= 0 && space[i].y < 0)
        {

            if(space[i].x <= r && space[i].y >= d && d)
                printf("YES\n");

            else
                printf("NO\n");
        }
        //left-up
        else if(space[i].x < 0 && space[i].y >= 0)
        {

            if(space[i].x >= l && space[i].y <= u && l)
                printf("YES\n");

            else
                printf("NO\n");
        }
        //left-down
        else if(space[i].x < 0 && space[i].y < 0)
        {

            if(space[i].x >= l && space[i].y >= d && l && d)
                printf("YES\n");
            else
                printf("NO\n");
        }

    }




    return 0;
}
```

Is there any mistake in the malloc portion? Because in codeblocks 20.03 this code is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your program allocates just 20,000 bytes for the route string, but the problem specification says its length may be up to 10<sup>5</sup>, which is 100,000. You can expect any online judge test to stress the limits of the problem, so it will overrun the allocated space and corrupt memory.

It would take 100,001 bytes to be sure of holding the route string, including the terminating null character. However, there is no need to hold the route string at all. The input can be read character by character, and the direction counts `l`, `r`, `u`, and `d` can be incremented while the input is being read. Further, there is no need for an array of strings for the test cases; each test case can be fully processed before going on to the next, so there is no need to hold the data for multiple test cases in memory at once.